# Extract Full Data From Json With C#

Tags: c#

I need your help how do i go to the next data and follow them, the json is below

```
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
     "before": "QVFIUkpHTGJjc2RVTDY5YUpnb240dEdCbTVKZAGNhZAjJSNmY0TzJVRWhNcXk4eVROVU5nRzJUWFFuS1dZAMDhhVFNHMEJ6X0ZAqQTlHMmlfRk9ISHo0Qkw3MTdn",
     "after": "QVFIUlFsWXF0OUJLVXdkb0Y3TXBhVG5LVUxCeVN1ZAjhoeVNudkdHXy1tZAWZAOTW1DbzZAIOTJmNGw1RjlKS3liYXJJdWtKMXAtQXNHM0NjVGIzN1JnY3hVTFVB"
  },
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1512513832114020/members?access_token=token&pretty=1&fields=name&limit=100&after=QVFIUlFsWXF0OUJLVXdkb0Y3TXBhVG5LVUxCeVN1ZAjhoeVNudkdHXy1tZAWZAOTW1DbzZAIOTJmNGw1RjlKS3liYXJJdWtKMXAtQXNHM0NjVGIzN1JnY3hVTFVB",
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1512513832114020/members?access_token=token&pretty=1&fields=name&limit=100&before=QVFIUkpHTGJjc2RVTDY5YUpnb240dEdCbTVKZAGNhZAjJSNmY0TzJVRWhNcXk4eVROVU5nRzJUWFFuS1dZAMDhhVFNHMEJ6X0ZAqQTlHMmlfRk9ISHo0Qkw3MTdn"
```

}

Its facebook graph api, so after the extract done, its move to next page until data empty.

Comment: How about writing a `while` loop statement?

Comment: You can use newtonsoft json for easier use library, but you can also get the data by process the string.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

in C#, you must use newtonsoft.dll to process data of JSON.
You can download at:  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json